# mergExt - mergAV show all the video while recording

Tags: video-recording, livecode

It's possible to use the Video Gravity Mode AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect in preview?

Currently I only can use the AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill which preserves the aspect ratio, but fills the available screen area, cropping the video. I would like to give user the possibility to se the video preserving the aspect ratio and leaving black bars where the video does not fill the available screen area. If this possible or maybe planned for a future releases?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no option for changing the video gravity of the camera view but it could be something I add in the future.

Comment: Thank you Monte, great news.